# How do you remove residual Lawesson's reagent after thionation?

Tags: synthesis, medicinal-chemistry

I am currently synthesizing a peptidomimetic bioisostere that replaces an oxygen with a sulfur. I use lawesson's reagent to achieve this, and althought the reaction works and despite running it through a column ( 80 mL silica, 10:1 DCM:MeOH) There is still a lot of residual lawesson's reagent left over. Does anyone have experience with this reagent and removing it? Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I would suggest recolumning with a gradient of MeOH in DCM starting at zero% MeOH.

Comment: Interesting, my current gradient is 30:1, 20:1, 10:1..so youre suggesting  starting at 0 % MeOH ? What would a typical gradient that follows 0% look like? I'm new to chemistry

Comment: My recollection is that Lawseson's residues are fairly non-polar and elute early so I would go with several column volumes of neat DCM before starting at 1% MeOH for a couple of column volumes then 2% etc. This means a much shallower gradient and more fractions than you've previously uxed.